# Two different layouts with one stylesheet for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, model-view-controller, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two different layouts and two different stylesheets (one for each) used by one controller/action.

How can I prevent the following error?

**line #5 raised:** `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required`

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Blog</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
```

The same error occurs when the other layout is loaded, but `"application"` is then `"another_stylesheet_file_in_the_same_folder"`.

What I don't understand is why the *application.css* file was able to be loaded while the second layout has another `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "another_css_file" %>` line in there instead.

Could the reason be the asset pipeline which is loading both of these stylesheets?
Or is it just an inheritance issue?

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
    current_uri = request.env['PATH_INFO']
    if current_uri.include?('diashow')
      @diashow = true
      return 'diashow'
    else
      @diashow = false
      return 'application'
    end
  end
...
```

Is the application layout already loaded before this code has been executed?

Is there a way to solve this by using the `before_filter`?
Or is it just stupid what I try to do? :)

**EDIT:**

Rails console:

```
Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.4ms)
Compiled application.css  (2ms)  (pid 23453)
Compiled diashow.css  (1ms)  (pid 23453)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 348ms
```

Why is it loading both of these files? It should only load one of them.

Comment: Show us contents of `application.css` and `diashow.css`

Comment: Is it necessary? They are still both the same. But I can't imagine that this could be the problem.

Comment: If I would change tag names in one of these css files, the whole thing would be useless. I just changed the content of some tags, but this could not be the solution and yes, it's not.

Comment: My guess is that both these files include this command: `require_tree .`. This would make them include each other.

Comment: Ah! Nice! I thought that `require_tree` line can't do something while it is commented out. Thanks Sergio! Pity I can't vote on you. :(

Comment: Posted as an answer. Now you can :-)

Comment: Added explanation about comments also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both these files probably include this command:

```
 = require_tree .
```

This would make them recursively include each other.

These directives are "commented out" to maintain syntax correctness of js/css files. Asset Pipeline will nevertheless parse these comments and execute directives.

Comment: Thanks Sergio! I thought that `require_tree` line can't do something while it is commented out. ;)